# Best temporary storage option for count value (preferably not a DB but a service) on AWS while running a SQS triggered function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, count, amazon-sqs, eventtrigger, key-value-store

**The situation**

Currently, I am using an Amazon SQS queue that triggers a Lambda function to process new messages upon arrival to the queue. Those Lambda functions are being moved to a DLQ (Dead-Letter Queue) upon failure.

In-order to seed the SQS queue, I am using a CRON that runs every day and inserts the available jobs into the queue.

I want to issue a summarizing alert/email once the processing of all the new jobs the CRON has inserted for the day are done or been processed, along with the details about how many successful, failing and total jobs were originally issued in that day.

**The problem:**

As the Lambda functions run separately, and the fact that I want to keep it that way, I was wondering what would be the best service to use in order to store the temporary count value (at least two out of the three counts are needed among the total, succeeding and failing counts)?

I was thinking about DynamoDB, but every DB seems to be an overkill for that, and won't be cost-effective either. S3 also doesn't seem to be the most practical/preferred for this type of solution.  I can also use SQS (as its "storage" is somewhat designed for cases with relatively small data storage such as these) with an identifier "count" that will be updated by every Lambda function, but knowing which Lambda function was the last requires checking the whole queue, which seems like over-complicating that.

Any other AWS service that comes up to mind?

Here is a good [listing of Storage Options in the AWS Cloud](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Storage/aws-storage-options.pdf) (2013, but includes some of that options available today as well).

Comment: Does it have to be permanent data stoer? What about fast in-memory ones, like ElastiCache? There is also parameter store, you could store a simple counter parameter there?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be a permanent data store. in-memory ones can be great, but the setup should be minimal, I guess in this case parameter store is preferred? It will have to be deleted at the end of the process, which I guess the best way to know would be to check if the SQS queue is empty.

Comment: Parameter store is the simplest I can think off, but its not atomic. Meaning that your lambda has to get its current value, increment, and upload. So if you have multiple lambdas running in parallel, they can be incrementing same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) can be used as a 'mini-database'.

It requires AWS credentials to access (which would be available to the Lambda functions or whatever code you are running to perform this check) but has no operational cost.

From [PutParameter - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_PutParameter.html):

> Parameter Store offers a standard tier and an advanced tier for parameters. Standard parameters have a **content size limit of 4 KB** and can't be configured to use parameter policies. You can create a **maximum of 10,000 standard parameters for each Region** in an AWS account. Standard parameters are offered at **no additional cost**.

You could run into problems if multiple processes try to update the parameters simultaneously, but hopefully your use-case is pretty simple.